# How to prove that multinomial theorem in combination

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Show that the coefficient of $x^n$ in $$\left ( 1+x+x^{2} \right )^n$$  is
$$1 + \frac{n(n-1)}{(1!)^2}+\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-3))}{(2!)^2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot $$

I know that this is some kind of combinatorial proof. My biggest problem is that I've never really done a proof.

$$(1+x+x^2)=(1+x(1+x))^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^k(1+x)^k$$
I didn't understand this hint?

Thank you for reading my word

Comment: Mathematical induction might help.

Comment: From binomial formula is $(1+x)^k=\sum_{j=0}^{k}\binom{k}{j} x^j$. For $j=n-k$ and $k=0,...n$, after multiplication you should get coefficient of $x^n$.

Comment: $\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^k(1+x)^k=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^k\sum_{j=0}^{k} \binom{k}{j}x^j$ For $j=n-k$, Is this right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *Note:* One approach to solve the problem is to *transform* $\left ( 1+x+x^{2} \right )^n$ so that the coefficient  of $x^n$ can be easily seen to be of the form
>   \begin{align*}
> 1 + \frac{n(n-1)}{(1!)^2}+\frac{n\cdot (n-1)\cdot (n-2)\cdot (n-3))}{(2!)^2}+\cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot \cdot\tag{1}
> \end{align*}
>   The *hint*
>   \begin{align*}
> (1+x+x^2)=(1+x(1+x))^n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} \binom{n}{k}x^k(1+x)^k\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
>   shows some of these proper transformation steps.

Let's have a look at it in detail.

But first it's helpful to introduce following notation:

> We use the so-called
>
> - *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$
>
> which extracts the coefficient of $x^n$ from a polynomial $p(x)$
>
> $$[x^n]p(x)=[x^n]\sum_{k=0}^{M}a_kx^k=a_n$$
>
> The coefficient of $x^n$ of $\left ( 1+x+x^{2} \right )^n$ can therefore be written as
>   $$[x^n]\left ( 1+x+x^{2} \right )^n$$

It's also convenient to write (1) in a more compact form.

> Let's consider the general term (i.e. the $k$-th summand)
>   \begin{align*}
> &\frac{n(n-1)\cdot\ldots\cdot(n-2k+1)}{(k!)^2}\\
> &\qquad\qquad=\frac{n!}{(k!)^2(n-2k)!}\\
> &\qquad\qquad=\frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}\frac{(n-k)!}{k!(n-2k)}\\
> &\qquad\qquad=\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{k}
> \end{align*}

Now we can formulate the problem more concise:

> **Problem:** Show that
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n](1+x+x^2)=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{k}\tag{3}
> \end{align*}
>
> If you check the right hand side of (3) and calculate terms with small $k$ you will see that it corresponds with (1). Observe also that in (3) the factor $\binom{n-k}{k}=0$ if $k>[\frac{n}{2}]$ so that in fact only the first half of the summands will contribute values $> 0$.
>
> **Calculation:**
>   \begin{align*}
> [x^n]&(1+x+x^2)^n=[x^n]\left(1+x(1+x)\right)^n=[x^n]\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}x^k(1+x)^k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}[x^{n}]x^k(1+x)^k\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{linearity of $[x^n]$ operator}\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}[x^{n-k}](1+x)^k\qquad\qquad\qquad[x^{n}]x^k=[x^{n-k}]1\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}[x^{n-k}]\sum_{j=0}^k\binom{k}{j}x^j\qquad\qquad n-k=j\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^n\binom{n}{k}\binom{k}{n-k}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad  k\rightarrow n-k\\
> &=\sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}\binom{n-k}{k}
> \end{align*}